# How to center Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to **center Linear layout** contents to center. This linear layout is inside the Scroll View and Relative Layout. This is my code given below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Services" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/service"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sday"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eng1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tamil"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eng2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eng3"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/wday"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eng4"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eng5"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/mass"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mass1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/novena"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wed"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody suggest me where I am going wrong ? When I use **android:layout_gravity="center"** nothing is happening..Suggest me plzz...

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but it is `android:gravity="center"` not `android:layout:gravity="center"`.

Comment: set  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" this attribute on textViews in your linearlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="center"` on your `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Alternatively, use `android:layout_gravity="center"` on your **content** views:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sday"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

---

`android:gravity="xxx"` says something about the positioning of the **contents** of this `ViewGroup`.

`android:layout_gravity="xxx"` says something about the positioning of **this** `View` **within** its parent.

Comment: yeahh Sure...nd +1 que too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:gravity="center"` for `LinearLayout`.

```
     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting gravity to center like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the Linear layout to the correct parent via Design tab,  then add this to the xml:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```